# Wii and S-Video results in black white window

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-wii, monitor, pal

I've bought a third party Wii S-Video + Composite connection cable for my european black Wii (PAL / Wii Sports Resort + Wii Motion Plus edition). The connection of S-Video and my tv tuner card results in the following:

[image]

which transforms to:

[image]

and back...

The Wii "Screen" menu states that 480i is selected as output mode. My tv tuner card works perfectly with Xbox 360 S-video output when set as PAL 60.

Edit:
I should also mention, that I've read that the european PAL Wii isn't capable of S-Video. Even though, there are (third party) adapters availabe in the european market. But the screens attached show that there is something like a S-video signal, which is more than "not capable with S-video".

Answer (score 2):

Your Wii is probably set to PAL 50, which causes would cause similar problems. Setting the Wii to PAL 60 would work, http://www.nintendo.co.uk/NOE/en_GB/support/wii_support_5251_8159.html shows how to change that setting, under "Screen".

It's a "bit" of a pain when the screen looks like that but it's doable if you keep the wiimote in the same position when you can't see the screen. (My TV shows a few frames before a few seconds of and then repeats, don't know if your tuner does)

Comment: I already tried that. When switching to 50Hz mode, while the tv tuner is 60Hz mode the screen gets even more distorted. By switching the tuner card to 50Hz, I get the same results as before. The same happens vise versa when running 60Hz Wii with 50Hz TV tuner.

Comment: Oke, it could also be that the tuner expects 480p, while the Wii sends 480i, other than that I have no idea. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

European Wii consoles don't output S-Video. You can buy converters (a small box with some electronics in it) that take in YPbPr ("component video") and output S-Video.

I think the reason you're getting anything at all is that S-Video splits the video into 2 parts, luma (brightness) and chroma (colour), and the luma is present as it's also in the YPbPr output but the chroma isn't present because your Wii doesn't generate it.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. But stands the s-video limitation for my newer black edition?

Comment: Only difference between the two versions of the Wii is GameCube support - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/43275/is-there-a-functional-difference-between-black-family-edition-and-white-classic

Comment: No, I'm owning the black Wii from the "Wii Sports Resort Pak" which has been released alongside the Wiimotion Plus